# How can I display only two posts from each category in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have to display 2 posts from each category. The code below gets all the posts belong to each category. My structure is tab based. I am attaching the image of my design. My tabs contain "all (shows all posts)", "symptoms (shows posts related to symptoms only" etc. ,clicking on each tabs shows relevant posts.
 [image]

```
 <?php $recent = new WP_Query("post_type=post&posts_per_page=-1&orderby=date&order=DESC");
                $count=0;                         
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $c = get_the_category();
                    $cat =  $c[0]->cat_name;
                    $slug = $c[0]->category_nicename;
                    ?>
                    <div class="element-item transition <?php echo $slug;?>" data-category="<?php echo $slug;?>">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <div class="descrip">
                                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                             </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php

    $cat_args = array(
        'orderby'      => 'date',
        'order'        => 'DESC',
        'child_of'     => 0,
        'parent'       => '',
        'type'         => 'post',
        'hide_empty'   => true,
        'taxonomy'     => 'category',
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $cat_args );

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

        $query_args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'category_name'  => $category->slug,
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'orderby'        => 'date',
            'order'          => 'DESC'
        );

        $recent = new WP_Query($query_args);

        while( $recent->have_posts() ) :
            $recent->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="element-item transition <?php echo $category->slug;?>" data-category="<?php echo $category->slug;?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <div class="descrip">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                 </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

First you list all the categories, then in `foreach` loop through each, and query only 2 most recent ones.

Note that you can list any taxonomy this way. I just put

```
'taxonomy'     => 'category',
```

but this can be a taxonomy assigned to your custom post type for instance.

List of arguments looks kinda like this:

```
$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 1,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
    'pad_counts'               => false
);
```

Hope this helps.